# Multiple VBA Projects listed with "Reference to Normal" but can't remove them

Tags: vba, ms-word

[image]

I was working on create a Word macro in Microsoft VBA, and somehow it ended up creating a lot of these projects.  They look empty, but I can't remove them.  These documents don't exist, at least that I can see,  and I think they were created while I was debugging the original macro.

Comment: Have a look at Windows Task Manager and see if you have multiple instances of Word running, with one document (I.e. "project") open in each.